# Gulp task not compiling SASS

Tags: sass, gulp

I'm having some issues running a gulp task where my SASS won't be compiled if I include plumber in the below screenshot, but when I comment it out, the SASS is compiled no problem!

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening, I've updated my node versions and cleaned out node_modules and reinstalled them all but the issue persists.

Has anybody seen this issue before?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I needed to install both the 64 bit AND 32 bit versions of node, but I didn't know this until I installed yarn through Chocolatey and they were installed as dependencies.